# I can't go directly to a URL on my site after deploying to Render

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, render, web-deployment

I finally deployed my first app (on Render,) but now I'm having an issue. It works great if I just start at the '/' (like http://url.com/ and click around, but if I put any other url into my address bar (like http://url.com/login/) it just says not found, though like I said I can click the link I have on the site which uses navigate('/login/') and that works fine. What am I doing wrong here? Everything works fine if I run it from my computer.

Comment: can you follow the same step for Rewrite Rule  which display   on render?
https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app on render blog

Answer (score 2):

If you are using react for the development of your app, you can use **React Router** to handle the navigation of your routes. This is very easy and you can find instructions [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-react-router-version-6/).

To handle the client-side routing of your react components you can set up rewrite rules. You can do this without a code from your hosting provider. In this case login to render.com, go to the dashboard of your static website, on the left-hand side click on **Redirects/Rewrites**, and add new rules accordingly.

For example, if you want to go to the login section (http://url.com/login):

1. Add Rule
2. Source: /login
3. Destination: /
4. Action: Rewrite
5. Save Changes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the case where your url have params and you are working with render:

- Open : Redirect/Rewrites :
- Add Rules :

**Example : **

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JviBU.jpg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You probably didn't add the necessary redirects/rewrites.  [read about it here](https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33550852)