# My MERN website shows 'Not Found' on reload of web page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Problem is: when I try to generate lighthouse report for my project, when the home page reloads, it gives response 'Not Found'
I have hosted my website on render.com

Hosted website link: https://cookwell.onrender.com

- Whole code link: https://github.com/manastelavane/RecipeNew
- Only client side code: https://github.com/manastelavane/RecipeClient
- Only server side code: https://github.com/manastelavane/RecipeServer
- Only chat-server code: https://github.com/manastelavane/RecipeChatServer
  (chat server is not involved on home page, so you can ignore chat server)

I used Mongodb,Express,React-Redux,Nodejs stack for project.

Also, note that, after loading of home page('/'), user is automatically redirected to '/card?category=All&page=1'

Comment: This is the problem with static site hosting specifically when hosting a SPA (single page application) which react is. The way react works is that all the request is handled by single index.js file and all the routing logic is done from that file. Static site hosting like render.com may not know this so u need to configure it yourself. Here is a useful link to one of such articles. https://community.render.com/t/not-found-error-blank-page/6365

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223164/i-cant-go-directly-to-a-url-on-my-site-after-deploying-to-render

Comment: Thanks Milan Patel , Adding Rewrite in render.com worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `homepage` in your `package.json` file (Client side)

```
.
"homepage": "https://cookwell.onrender.com/"
.
```